# Check which Kinetic.Layer is on top

Tags: z-index, kineticjs, multi-layer

I have one stage and multiple layers which are superposed. I refer to each layer with a button. I must allow the user to draw on those multiple layers whenever he clicks on one button, and swap between them. How can I check which layer is on top of the others?

I tried `layer.getAbsoluteZIndex()` but it's not obvious. Is there a method that actually return true/false for example, maybe like `.isOnTop()`?

**EDIT :**

Well, I had to implement it by my own and it was okay I guess. The easiest solution was to add a boolean attribute `isOnTop` in the definition of each layer and make the appropriate tests and treatments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add a new method on the Kinetic.Stage:

```
  Kinetic.Stage.prototype.getTopLayer=function(){
      var layers=stage.find('Layer');
      var topLayerIndex=-100;
      var topLayer;
      for(var i=0;i<layers.length;i++){
          var index=layers[i].getAbsoluteZIndex();
          if(index>topLayerIndex){
              topLayerIndex=index;
              topLayer=layers[i];
          }        
      }
      return(topLayer);
  }
```

Then you can get the layer with the highest z-index like this:

```
  var myTopLayer = stage.getTopLayer();
```

Comment: Thank you, I think both your method and my solution do the same thing :-) I'll accept this.